# Unable to access functions with debugging from Angular

Tags: angular, debugging, typescript, rxjs

I use Angular debugging to test the functions of my project. I do not understand why some of my functions work and others do not.
Here is what I write on the console:

```
ng.probe($0).componentInstance.threadService.__proto__.getThreadFromSubscription('tEcho')
```

Here is an example of a function that works:

```
openSettings(): void {
document.getElementById('outside').style.display = 'block';
document.getElementById('chat-threads').classList.toggle('display-settings');
}
```

While this one does not work:

```
getThreadFromSubscription(threadId: string): Observable<Thread>{
  return this.threads
  .map( (threadDictionary: { [key: string]: Thread }) => {
    for (let key in threadDictionary) {
      if (threadDictionary[key].id == threadId)
        return threadDictionary[key];
    }
  });
```

It puts this as a mistake:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
```

I edit my variable threads like this :

```
this.threads = messageService.messages
  .map((messages: Message[]) => {
    const threads: { [key: string]: Thread } = {};
    messages.map((message: Message) => {
      threads[message.thread.id] = threads[message.thread.id] ||
        message.thread;

      const messagesThread: Thread = threads[message.thread.id];
      if (!messagesThread.lastMessage ||
        messagesThread.lastMessage.date < message.date) {
        messagesThread.lastMessage = message;
      }
    });
    return threads;
  });
```

and messageService.messages :

```
messages: Observable<Message[]>;

this.messages = this.updates
  .scan((messages: Message[],
         operation: IMessagesOperation) => {
      return operation(messages);
    },
    initialMessages)
  .publishReplay(1)
  .refCount();
```

I have the impression that the console does not know some of my variables that I initialize in my project. Have you ever had this problem ? And other question, do you know if it is possible to execute functions in my components with debugging?

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
EDIT

I rephrase my question. I use the debugging mode of angular to perform my functions according to my console, I write this :

```
ng.probe($0).componentInstance.chatService.__proto__.addNewMessage({
"id": "toto",
"body": "COUCOU", 
"author": "Toto"
})
```

When I execute my functions it shows me errors such as:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
```

I do not understand why because when I normally run them these work.

Do you know if there are parameters in the mode debugging of Angular ?

Comment: What is `this.threads`?

Comment: @echonax
It's a flow of Observable.
threads: Observable<{ [key: string]: Thread }>;

Comment: Where do you assign it? Is it defined by the time you use this method?

Comment: I edited my post. I assign it in a service 'threadService'.

Comment: then what is `messageService.messages`..

Comment: I have edited my post .